# Caching a WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, cache

Is there a recommended known-to-work way of caching a WordPress site running on Apache Httpd 2? Should I use a plug in or cache in Apache Httpd? If in Apache Httpd, should it be disk or memory cache? If as a plug in, which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WP-SuperCache is the defacto standard for caching WordPress pages and provides a good deal of flexibility.

Comment: With Apache's mem cache: 1.32 requests/sec, without it: 1.33 requests/sec. With WP-Super-cache: 1759.05 requests/sec (measured with  ab -n 100 http://localhost/). Wow! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My general experience is that the application level is a good place to start doing cache. It is the application which has the necessary information to do the smart choices.

Without have any specific experience of caching Wordpress the plugin [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) does look like a good option do consider. Not only is it well maintained, it also supports generating static html, which will save a lot of load on your web server.

Answer (score 0):

WP Super Cache as the others have said is a great plugin and works well. You may also want to consider doing some caching at the database level, a little love given to mysql can go a long way on a busy site, [mysqlreport](http://hackmysql.com/mysqlreport) is a great tool for understanding all the knobs and dials for tuning mysql.